# Display information of 1 table from 2 columns in the the search results. (PHP - Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a webpage that lets you browse different job offers, these ones are saved in a MySQL table called *“jobs”*

*“jobs”* has different columns, one of them being ***“basic”*** for the normal jobs and ***“op2”*** for premium jobs.

When performing a search I’m trying to be able to display both of these categories on my results, however I only have only been able to display one, not both.

I was able to display both of these jobs using:

```
 $premium_jobs = Posts::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')->where('type', 'op2')->where('status', 'active')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

However when using the filters to search for specific words, it works with the basic jobs but displays all of the premium jobs without applying any filter.

---

**Some queries that didn't worked:**

- Searches for basic jobs, but always displays all of the premium jobs no matter what the search was:

  ```
  $premium_jobs = Posts::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')->where('type', 'op2')->where('status', 'active')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
  ```

  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoUqE.png)
- Doesn't display premium jobs, only displays basic jobs:

  ```
  $premium_jobs = Posts::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')->where('type', 'op2')->where('type', 'basic')->where('status', 'active')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
  ```

  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3yNB.png)
- Doesn't display basic jobs, only displays premium jobs:

  ```
  $premium_jobs = $jobs->where('type', 'op2')->where('status', 'active')->paginate(15);
  ```

  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLgFa.png)
- Displays premium jobs and basic jobs, but also shows a duplicate of the basic jobs as a premium one:

  ```
  $premium_jobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')->paginate(15);
  ```

  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NZrJ.png)

---

**Controller:**

```
<?php  

class SearchController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request){

        $jobs = new Posts();
        if ($request->has('q')) {
            $jobs = $jobs->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%');
        }

        if (!empty($request->city)) {
            $city = Cities::where('name', $request->city)->first();
            $jobs = $jobs->where('city_id', $city->id);
        }

        if (!empty($request->min_salary)) {
            $jobs = $jobs->where('salary', '>', $request->min_salary);
        }

        if (!empty($request->jt)) {
            $job_type = JobTypes::where('name', $request->jt)->first();
            $jobs = $jobs->where('job_type_id', $job_type->id);
        }

        if (!empty($request->ex)) {
            $jobs = $jobs->where('experience', $request->ex);
        }

        if (!empty($request->cat)) {
            $category = Categories::where('name', $request->cat)->first();
            $jobs = $jobs->where('cat_id', $category->id);
        }


// PREMIUM JOBS

       $premium_jobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')->paginate(15);


// BASIC JOBS

        $basic_jobs = $jobs->where('type', 'basic')->where('status', 'active')->paginate(15);

        $cities = Cities::all();
        $job_types =  JobTypes::all();
        $categories =  Categories::all();

        return view('search.index', compact('basic_jobs', 'premium_jobs', 'request', 'cities', 'job_types', 'categories'));
    }

    ?>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the query you must use `orWhere`. [This Page](https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-tips-tricks) can help I think.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other job types??
If not try this

```
Posts::where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')->where('status', 'active')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

// To get both the jobs : 

$allJobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')->paginate(15);

// To get al basic jobs 

$allBasicJobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')->where('type', 'basic')->paginate(15);

// To get all premium jobs 

$allBasicJobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')->where('type', 'op2')->paginate(15);

// To search title in  basic jobs but get all premier jobs

$filteredBasicJobsAllPremiumJobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')
                                        ->where('type', 'op2')
                                        ->orWhere(function($q) use($request){
                                            return $q->where('type', 'basic')
                                                ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%');
                                        })
                                        ->paginate(15);

// To search title in  permium jobs but get all basic jobs

$filteredPremiumJobsAllBasicJobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')
                                        ->where('type', 'basic')
                                        ->orWhere(function($q) use($request){
                                            return $q->where('type', 'op2')
                                                ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%');
                                        })
                                        ->paginate(15);

// To search title in both basic and premium jobs

$filteredJobs = $jobs->where('status', 'active')
                    ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->q . '%')
                    ->paginate(15);
```